# how to manage lifetime of variable for multiple request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, global-variables

I have a variable in create method in controller ,is there any way to reuse that variable with the same value in update method. How can i pass this, or how can i maintain the lifetime for the multiple requests?

Example variable:

```
@m = Issue.where( :project_id => @project.id ).where( :issue => "xyz" )
```

Comment: What is the scope of this variable: Server side: For all requests to same web child process, all to same server, or all to the application? Client side: For all requests from same browsing session, all requests from same user, all requests from all users?

Comment: @Neil just restful way i m following!! same server but session may be different

Comment: @m =Issue.where(:project_id => @project.id).where(:issue => "xyz")

Comment: Anish: You have to fetch that data each time, it cannot be shared across the server, other than how you are already doing it - via the database. If performance is a concern, then you could cache the data (in e.g. memcache).

Comment: but after create action data would be change so i need it before it in update action

Comment: Yes that is correct. If you need this data in the update method, then you will need to fetch it again just before or during the update method.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, your requirement is to re-use data that was accessed during one call to your API (for creation of an API entity), during a separate call (an update). The data is fetched from the database in the first case.

*Just fetch the data again, using the same query.*

The database is the only data source easily accessible in both events, that will reliably hold an up-to-date value.

As this is for a RESTful API, there should be no other state information - everything should be in either the current request or the database.

If you want, you can cache data for performance, but Ruby variables are not a reliable or efficient way to do that (because there will be several Ruby processes running independently on the web server, and you don't get to manage them from the controller code) - instead you might want to consider something like `memcached` if the query is slow and its results are needed in many  API events. However, you should normally avoid caching data except where you have a real performance issue - because you will probably need to handle cache invalidation, too.

Comment: There may be many requests coming at the same time in the real world, only storing data in the database can ensure the correctness.